# How to make seaborn and bokeh plot publication level?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, bokeh

How would I make [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) and [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) plots to look professionally for a scientific paper:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone advise on some common practices when creating publication level figures in python?

Comment: 12% of papers uploaded to `arxiv.org` in 2018 used at least one matplotlib figure [[source](https://twitter.com/Xarthisius/status/1019018260942147584)]. So it can't be that bad, can it? Since noone knows about what you don't like about it, the question is clearly too broad. Consider asking specificically about what you don't like in your plot and how you would like to have it instead.

Comment: https://python-graph-gallery.com/seaborn/

Answer (score 3):

As @brentertainer pointed out in his comment, seaborn is a effectively a wrapper around [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) and with matplotlib you can do virtually anything. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) is a nice library, which can guide you and provide some overview on what is possible. One of the most important things to be comfortable with is the axes object, which you can modify to your specific use case (see example below). From seaborn there should be a way to access the axes object (and other matplotlib structures) to modify it to your delight.

I do almost all my publication figures with matplotlib, with some minor modifications, informed by the style rules of [Edward Tufte](https://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/). I use the following function, that I compiled/ aggregated from several stack overflow questions and tutorials. (I will do some research so give sources for this on monday). The function (in my case used for bar charts) takes an axes object and modifies it to remove some unneeded lines etc.

```
def tuftefy(ax):
    """Remove spines and tick position markers to reduce ink."""
    # 
    ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(True)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_color('grey')

    ax.grid(color="w", alpha=0.5)
    ax.get_yaxis().grid(True)
    ax.get_xaxis().grid(False)
```

However, this is a rough example of what you can do. Your main focus should be: What do I want to communicate with my figure. Pick a figure type that serves this purpose best (for example via the matplotlib example library and/ or your domain knowledge)  and apply a style that supports it.

Comment: We have styles for this. Check https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

Comment: What about bokeh?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `matplotlib`.  A non-python package that many physics journals like is `gnuplot`.  I would review the submission procedure for the journals you are aiming for also :)

Comment: Be aware `seaborn` is effectively a wrapper for `matplotlib`.

Comment: some python libs have `gnuplot` theme